# SDL_GL_GetAttribute() outputs zeroes?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm currently developing an SDL window which uses OpenGL.  When I initialise the `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(colours here... r, g, b etc.)` upon using error checks, the `SDL_GL_GetAttribute()` returns 0 for alpha, buffer, r, g, b and I think this is stopping me from creating the basic OpenGL triangle in the SDL window... I'm not sure.

I was hoping to get some directions on how to fix this issue.

Here's the code snippet below for initialising OpenGL and SDL:

```
 void Window::InitialiseSDL()
 {
 SDL_Init(  SDL_INIT_AUDIO  | SDL_INIT_EVENTS   | SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER
         |  SDL_INIT_HAPTIC | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK | SDL_INIT_TIMER
         |  SDL_INIT_VIDEO                                              );

Has_SDL_Init = SDL_WasInit(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

if (!(Has_SDL_Init & SDL_INIT_AUDIO)) // You may be thinking wtf here? But!   if one sub system were to break, i'd know which one it exactly was.
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("Class Window.h ----> InitialiseSystem() ----> SDL_INIT_AUDIO Has failed to initialise.", state);
}
if (!(Has_SDL_Init & SDL_INIT_EVENTS))
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("Class Window.h ----> InitialiseSystem() ----> SDL_INIT_EVENTS Has failed to initialise.", state);
}
if (!(Has_SDL_Init & SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER))
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("Class Window.h ----> InitialiseSystem() ----> SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER Has failed to initialise.", state);
}
if (!(Has_SDL_Init & SDL_INIT_HAPTIC))
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("Class Window.h ----> InitialiseSystem() ----> SDL_INIT_HAPTIC Has failed to initialise.", state);
}
if (!(Has_SDL_Init & SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK))
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("Class Window.h ----> InitialiseSystem() ----> SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK Has failed to initialise.", state);
}
if (!(Has_SDL_Init & SDL_INIT_TIMER))
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("Class Window.h ----> InitialiseSystem() ----> SDL_INIT_TIMER Has failed to initialise.", state);
}
if (!(Has_SDL_Init & SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("Class Window.h ----> InitialiseSystem() ----> SDL_INIT_VIDEO Has failed to initialise.", state);
}

int r, g, b, a, minor, major, visual, depthSize, stencil, buffer, dblbuffer;
int core, flagsss;

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, &visual);


SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, &major);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, &minor);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);                  // Forces the use of Modern OpenGL. 
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, &core);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_FLAG);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &flagsss);

// They all fail from this point below ( Only in SDL init method )

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 3);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, &r);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 5);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, &g);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 5);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, &b);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 1);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE,&a);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, &depthSize);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 5);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, &stencil);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 24);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &buffer);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, &dblbuffer);

this->GameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
                                    this->windowWidth, this->windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
if (!GameWindow)
{
    ShutDownSystem();
}

SDL_SetWindowResizable(GameWindow, SDL_TRUE);
}

void Window::InitialiseOpenGL()
{
OpenGL_Context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(GameWindow);
SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

if (OpenGL_Context == nullptr)
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("LegendRenderer ----> InitialiseOpenGL() ----> Failed to create an OpenGL context for SDL.", state);
    SetWindowEngineState(*state);
}

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum OpenGLError = glewInit();
if (OpenGLError != GLEW_OK)
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("LegendRenderer ----> InitialiseOpenGL() ----> Failed to Initialise GLEW.", state);
    SetWindowEngineState(*state);
}

printf("OpenGL loaded\n");
printf("Vendor:   %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
printf("Renderer: %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
printf("Version:  %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));


if (SDL_GL_GetSwapInterval < 0)
{
    error.Fatal_SDL_Error("LegendRenderer ----> InitialiseOpenGL() ----> Failed to set frame buffer interval for SDL.", state);
    SetWindowEngineState(*state);
}

int w, h;
SDL_GetWindowSize(GameWindow, &w, &h);
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: The bit-depth you assign look rather strange to me. I highly doubt that you will get a r3-g5-b5-a1 format.

Answer (score 2):

[`SDL_GL_GetAttribute()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_GetAttribute) (emphasis mine):

> Use this function to get the actual value for an attribute **from the current [OpenGL] context**.

You're calling `SDL_GL_GetAttribute()` well before you even have a window, much less a current OpenGL context.

Call `SDL_GL_GetAttribute()` *after* you've successfully created a window & OpenGL context, and made the context current via `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent()` (well, not technically required because `SDL_GL_CreateContext()` will leave the created context current).

For instance you may have requested 5 red bits but the OpenGL context you eventually get may provide 8 bits.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information. I've made the changes you specified and it has helped, but it turns out this wasn't the issue. In my code, I was calling glClear on more than one occasion and it wiped the rendered objects off screen. This ended up being the issue, which in fairness could not have been identified by the code I posted, but thank you for the help. Much appreciated :)